# MongoDB Как сортировать в обе стороны от числа?

Tags: mongodb

Допустим, в коллекции есть такие документы:

```
{name: "Test 1", value: "1"}
{name: "Test 2", value: "2"}
{name: "Test 3", value: "3"}
{name: "Test 4", value: "4"}
{name: "Test 5", value: "5"}
{name: "Test 6", value: "6"}
```

Выбираем медиану значений value ([1,2,3,4,5,6]) - 3.5
Нужно отсортировать документы, чтобы значения шли от медианы (3.5) в обе стороны:

```
{name: "Test 3", value: "3"}
{name: "Test 4", value: "4"}
{name: "Test 2", value: "2"}
{name: "Test 5", value: "5"}
{name: "Test 1", value: "1"}
{name: "Test 6", value: "6"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение `value: "1"` не подходит для математических операций, нужно исправить тип со строки на число.

Я буду исходить из того, что данные вставлены по принципу `db.data.insert({name: "Test 1", value: 1});`.

Итак, нужно сделать вычисляемое поле, по которому отсортировать. Для этого нужно вычесть из `value` 3.5 и получить абсолютное значение. То есть `abs(value - 3.5)`.

Для этого нужно использовать [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/), в котором добавить [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), где с помощью [функций](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) вычислить значение:

```
db.data.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": 1,
            "value": 1,
            "orderBy": {
                $abs: {
                    $add: ["$value", -3.5]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {"$sort": {"orderBy": 1}}
]);
```

Результат:

```
{ "name" : "Test 3", "value" : 3, "orderBy" : 0.5 }
{ "name" : "Test 4", "value" : 4, "orderBy" : 0.5 }
{ "name" : "Test 2", "value" : 2, "orderBy" : 1.5 }
{ "name" : "Test 5", "value" : 5, "orderBy" : 1.5 }
{ "name" : "Test 1", "value" : 1, "orderBy" : 2.5 }
{ "name" : "Test 6", "value" : 6, "orderBy" : 2.5 }
```

Еще раз повторю, что `value` должно быть числом, а не строкой, иначе будет ошибка. Либо нужно сделать преобразование типов через [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/#mongodb-expression-exp.-toInt), но эта операция доступна в Mongo 4+, и я не могу проверить. Но должно быть так:

```
"orderBy": {
    $abs: {
        $add: [
            {$toInt: "$value"}, -3.5
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибся в теме, это значение в реальной бд является числом :)
Благодарю за ваш ответ!